# Spring Boot Email sending error all the configuration been done right still having issues

Tags: java, spring

I am not able to send mail in spring boot I have written the whole configuration right for sending mail but its not working I am not able to solve this problem.
This is my bean for sending mail

```
@Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);
    mailSender.setUsername("xxxxxx");
    mailSender.setPassword("fubwbpumstgwnxef");
    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    return mailSender;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added this in your applications properties also like this:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=xxxxxxxxx
spring.mail.password=xxxxxxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: thanks i was missing this part. Now my code is working fine.